# Xcode constraint error messages

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can anyone help me to understand the error messages from xcode during run-time:

```
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try
 this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) 
 find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If
 you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to
 the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
 (
     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1b886330 H:[UILabel:0x1b885ed0]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1b885980 )>",
     "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1b886360 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x1b885ed0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1b885980 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1b87e8c0 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1b885980(0)]>"
 )

 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
 <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1b886330 H:[UILabel:0x1b885ed0]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x1b885980 )>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use autoresizing and constraints together; you'll have a bad time. As the error says, refer to the docs on `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. You probably want to set this to `NO` on your view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apple's WWDC 2012 Videos on AutoLayout, especially the part about the Visual Language:

[Introduction to Auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)

[Auto layout By Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=232)

[Mastering Auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=228)

There's also an Autolayout video in WWDC 2013, on how to work with Auto Layout in XCode 5.

Answer (score 0):

What's really weird is this bit: H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x1b885980(0)]

I might be mistaken but isn't this saying that the width of the cell's content view is zero? How can that be? Does anyone know why that might happen? I'm seeing a similar issue myself where the width is zero for the cell...